# Redirect to a new form in Django Admin on Save

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

Hi I am creating a trouble ticket app for my company, and I want to redirect the user to a new form where he will specify the diagnose and solution he offered. 
my admin is 
Basically, Right now my code is calling the first form, when the obj created is new or the status is open and it is calling the ClosedForm when my status is closed.

What I want is that, when the user changes the status from Open to Closed and saves the ticekt, he is redirected to ClosedForm

Thanks

```
class TicketFormClosed(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = ('status','call_sheet_number','diagnose','solution','call_attend_date',)

class TicketForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        exclude = ('call_sheet_number','diagnose','solution','call_attend_date',)

class TicketAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(TicketAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        if obj == None or obj.status=='Open':
            form = TicketForm   
        else:
            form = TicketFormClosed
        return form
```

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at the ModelAdmin that is used for user creation

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the source code for admin.ModelAdmin. You will find the overridable hooks for redirecting there.

for example, search for HttpResponseRedirect in
django/contrib/admin/options.py
and you'll see the default flow playing out.